# Move controls programmatically in a method warns 'method not found' and 'control may not respond to'

Tags: objective-c, methods, uitextfield, uilabel, uicontrol

I have a UISegmentedView that I use to present the user with an option on one of two calculations they can do in my program. If the segmented control is one way, it should show 4 text boxes and their labels, if the other only 3 (and the calculation would change as well).

This all works, my problem is with moving the controls (I want to hide the ones you won't need, as well as move the controls on the screen to make it look nice)

I would like to put this in one method, and just pass the UIControl to move it. For example, in my .h

```
-(void) moveControlUp:(UIControl*)controlToMove;
```

Then, in my .m

```
- (void)moveControlUp:(UIControl*)controlToMove
{
    controlToMove.frame = CGRectMake(controlToMove.frame.origin.x, controlToMove.frame.origin.y - 39, controlToMove.frame.size.width, controlToMove.frame.size.height); 
}
```

and then when I actually want to move the controls (labelPointsHeader is a UILabel, textPointsName is a text box):

```
[labelPointsHeader moveControlUp];
[textPointsName moveControlUp];
```

This doesn't work, and I get two errors. "UILabel may not respond to '-moveControlUp'" and "Method '-moveControlUp' not found (return type defaults to id). I crash when I hit this, stating that 'unrecognized selector sent to instance'.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In which class did you define these methods? (doesn't appear to be a category)

Let's say you defined them in SomeClass, then you need to do this:

[someInstanceOfSomeClass moveControlUp:labelPointsHeader];

Right now you are sending a message to a UILabel in the first case, but UILabel does not have this method. The method is in whichever class you defined it.

Comment: They are in the same class, so would it just be [self moveControlUp:labelPointsHeader] ?

Comment: Assuming self is the correct instance for this, yes. Sounds like you may be a little unclear on class versus instance(object?)

Comment: self is correct. I understand the difference, just not thinking clearly when it came to this.

Comment: Also, the other warning was just due to a cast.